# Redirecting https//example.com to https://www.example.com -opencart v 2.2.0.0

Tags: apache, .htaccess, opencart2.x

all cases work fine except when redirecting https//example.com to https://www.example.com it stays the same https://example.com

I have tried most of the solutions in this forum but non worked for me
- my certificate is good for both "www.example.com" and example.com domain.
- I modified the fix for url.php

-htaccess: (i did try different solutions here)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

admin/config.php

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://www.example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.example.com/');
```

config.php

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/');
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will redirect all of the requests for yourdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com. This can be done by adding the following lines at the beginning of the .htaccess file in your public_html folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please check - [reference](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_redirect_nonwww_urls_to_www/)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it doesn't work for this case https://example.com. it will keep it the same

Comment: Please check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830801/problem-with-redirecting-example-com-example-com-to-www-example-com-for-http?rq=1